# Does monotouch support multi-file assemblies through modules?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm creating a cross platform set of applications, and some of the assemblies are constructed as multi-file assemblies using a set of modules compiled under visual studio 2010.  Does the monotouch compiler support multi-file assemblies like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a MonoTouch Library project to do this, however you will have to compile the library for MonoTouch.

To do this properly, here is an example:

- On Windows create 2 projects `MyApp` and `MyApp.Code` (a class library project)
- On iOS create 2 projects `MyApp` and `MyApp.Code` (a MonoTouch library project), in a different folder in your source control, of course
- Put all the code into `MyApp.Code` (Windows version), on iOS "Link-In" every file you want to add the to the project from the Windows copy.  This keeps one copy of the file, but allows you to compile for multiple platforms
- `MyApp` will just contain UI-specific code on both platforms and is completely different on both platforms
- Add `#if IPHONE` or `#if WINDOWS` preprocessor directives anywhere you might need them throughout the `MyApp.Code` project

Rinse and repeat if you want to do the same for Mono for Android, Windows Phone, etc.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. I'm asking about multi-file assemblies in which different projects are compiled as 'modules', not assemblies and then are later stitched together with the assembly linker tool to create one dll. All the code in the different modules is all considered part of the same assembly for type discovery purposes.

Comment: I would just make one project in your case then.  The project can have as many files as you like and link-in as many files as you like.  I take this route myself occasionally, putting code that are in other projects on Windows just in a sub-folder within my iOS app's project.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  That would work because on windows we use git submodules to link in the binary modules, we could just submodule the actual source in the case of the MonoTouch project.  Thanks.